# Changing select value if is checked doesn't work

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to multiply by 2 the calculation if a checkbox is checked, but doesn't work

```
$('#kilometros').keyup(function () {

    var kilometros = parseFloat($(this).val().toString().replace(",", "."));
    var precioKilometros = parseFloat($('#precioKilometros').val());
    if ($('#retorno').is(':checked')) {
        var retorno = 2.0;
    } else {  
        var retorno = 1.0;
    }

    var totalKilometros = (kilometros * precioKilometros * retorno).toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");
    $('#totalKilometros').html(totalKilometros);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3k9sz/1/

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes with this? A jsFiddle would be helpful as well.

Comment: try `if($('#retorno').attr('checked') == true){...`

Comment: The fiddle you just attached doesn't match the code in your question, and the code in your question _works_ as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/3k9sz/1/ Is your _real_ question "This code only works when typing in the field, so how do I make it work in response to the checkbox being clicked too?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var retorno = $('#retorno').is(':checked') ? 2.0 : 1.0;
```

Instead of this:

```
if ($('#retorno').is(':checked')) {
    var retorno = 2.0;
} else {  
    var retorno = 1.0;
}
```

So, your code should be like:

```
$('#kilometros').keyup(function () {
    var kilometros = parseFloat($(this).val().toString().replace(",", "."));
    var precioKilometros = parseFloat($('#precioKilometros').val());
    var retorno = $('#retorno').is(':checked') ? 2.0 : 1.0;
    var totalKilometros = (kilometros * precioKilometros * retorno).toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");
    $('#totalKilometros').html(totalKilometros);
});
```

Comment: In my opinion that would be neater, but why would it fix the problem? (Why doesn't the OP's code work?)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, but now I have another problem, after it is done the calculation, and displays the result, I try to check and uncheck the checkbox and not done the calculation again, you have any idea how to solve it? thanks for the interest

Comment: Add `$("#retorno").click(function() { $("#kilometros").keyup(); });`.